# Click event only triggered after refresh

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Like the title says:

I have a page with a few buttons and jquery script as following:

```
    $( document ).bind( 'mobileinit', function(){
  $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.text = "loading";
  $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.textVisible = false;
  $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.theme = "a";
  $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.html = "";
});

$(document).bind('pagecreate', function(event){
// New model form submittion

     $('#new-model-submit').click(function(){
          // do
     });

     // Compatibility

     // Switch brands
     $('#brands').change(function(){
         // do something
     });

     // Add model to compatibility
     $('input[type=checkbox]').live("change", function(){
         // do something

     });

     // Specificaties
     $("#add-product-spec").click(function(){
         // do something
     });

     $("#save-product-specs").click(function(){
         // Do something
     });

     // Foto's
     $("#add-product-foto").click(function(){
        // Do something
     });

     $("#save-product-fotos").click(function(){
        // Do something
     });

});
```

The problem is that these events do not get triggered when the page is first loaded. However, when I press <kbd>F5</kbd> and refresh the page the buttons do work. Why is this? Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 3):

JQuery Mobile works a little differently. If a link directs you to a page on the same domain, JQuery mobile will intercept that event and, instead, make an ajax request then insert it into the DOM. One way to get around this is to use `live` for your click events. i.e.

```
// Specificaties
$("#add-product-spec").live("click", function(){
 // do something 
});
```

This will tell the browser to keep an eye out for the "click" event on anything that matches the "#add-product-spec" selector regardless of when it was inserted into the DOM.

*Edit*

Another thing you could try is using `PageShow` instead of `PageCreate`. JQuery mobile's `PageCreate` event, if I remember correctly, only fires the first time you load the page.

Comment: Will definitly check this out